# Formal language theory (regular expressions and regular languages) - concept of "OR"

Tags: regex, logic, regular-language, formal-languages

Okay, so in programming the logical OR symbol (typically ||) when applied to operands a and b, that is, a || b, means that either a or b can be true, OR both can be true.  If you want only one to be true, you use XOR (sometimes, the ^ symbol.)

However, in formal language theory, the concept of OR (typically the + symbol) seems to imply exclusive-or (xor) instead of regular OR.  For example, if we describe a language L with a regular expression aa + bb + ab, a valid string (word) from the language would be one of those (aa, bb, or ab), not some concatenation of them.  To do that, you must use the Kleene closure, as in (aa + bb + ab)*, right?

Perhaps I'm just thinking of + as being defined in a peculiar way, or perhaps it's that the operands are no longer Boolean?

I'm just looking for verification if I seem to be understanding that + (OR) has a seemingly different meaning in formal language / computational modeling than it does in programming languages.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The formal language OR *is* an inclusive ("regular") OR. E.g., the regular language `ab* + a*b` *includes* strings that are in both `ab*` and `a*b` (i.e., the string `ab`).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the operator - the + in regular expressions really does mean the same thing as union of sets - the problem is with your understanding of the operands. Specifically, in your regular expression, aa + bb + ab, aa does not represent a *string* over your alphabet, but a sub-regular expression. Regular expressions describe *sets* of strings; so the regular expression aa describes the set of strings {aa}. So, the regular expression aa + bb + ab describes the set of strings {aa} union {bb} union {ab} = {aa, bb, ab}. The exclusive-or of set theory, symmetric difference, does not have an operator in the regular expression syntax. We can recursively define the language of a regular expression, written L(r) for regular expression r, as follows:

- L(r) = {r}, if r is a string over the alphabet;
- L(r) = L(s)L(t) if r = st;
- L(r) = L(s)* if r = s*;
- L(r) = L(s) union L(t) if r = s + t.